# Install torrent tracker on Ubuntu

Tags: server, bittorrent, tracker

Help me, please.
How can I configure and start a Torrent tracker on ubuntu? I have tried the Xbt tracker but it's not working. I have to make a torrent file and also manage seeders and leeches etc.

Comment: Please include in your question the way in which xbt is 'not working', and what steps you have already taken to try and fix it.

Comment: first i download xbt ,g++,bost. After that, I run CMake . command it execute properly after that I run the make command. Copy the xbt_tracker file and xl config file to another directory
Import the SQL file but it has just four tables. when I am going to ./xbt_tracker it shows an SQL error for a table not found I create tables and this error resolved but nothing happened